# In C#, how to know if a thread is waiting to enter write lock for ReaderWriterLockSlim?

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, parallel-processing, thread-safety

I am trying to implement the ReaderWriterLockSlim for a list. I would like each thread to be able to read from the list at once, but only one thread to be permitted to "wait" for the write lock. If a thread attempts to gain control of the write lock while another thread is already writing or waiting to write, I would like it not to wait for the lock. I have found the [TryEnterReadLock(Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302037(v=vs.110).aspx) method, but from my understanding, it will only wait until the calling thread can gain control of the write lock or the timeout is reached. I would try this with a timeout of "0", however, I don't think this will work since if other threads possess the read lock, it will timeout before gaining access to the write lock. I know I could use a variable to represent whether or not a thread is writing or waiting to write, but I wanted to know if there is a more professional way of doing this (I'd prefer not to have to create another variable and consequently have to create a mutex lock for it).

Answer (score 1):

Move the logic further back, Use `TryEnterUpgradeableReadLock` on the readers with a 0 timeout, then that one reader becomes your writer waiting for the other readers to finish.

```
public void YourFunction()
{
    bool enteredUpgLock = false;
    bool enteredWriteLock = false;

    try
    {
        //Preemptively take a upgradeable read lock, only one thread can do this.
        enteredUpgLock = _readerWriterLock.TryEnterUpgradeableReadLock(0);

        try
        {
            //If we don't have the upgradeable lock take a normal read lock.
            if (!enteredUpgLock)
            {
                _readerWriterLock.EnterReadLock();
            }

            DoReadWork();
        }
        finally
        {
            //Release the read lock if we had it.
            if(!enteredUpgLock)
                _readerWriterLock.ExitReadLock();
        }

        try
        {
            if (enteredUpgLock)
            {
                //We held the upgradeable lock, wait forever till we can take it.
                _readerWriterLock.EnterWriteLock();
                enteredWriteLock = true;
            }
            else
            {
                //We did not have the upgrade lock, try to take the write lock but if we can't bail out.
                enteredWriteLock = _readerWriterLock.TryEnterWriteLock(0);
                if(!enteredWriteLock)
                    return;
            }

            DoWriteWork();
        }
        finally 
        {
            if(enteredWriteLock)
                _readerWriterLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
    finally 
    {
        //If we had the upgradeable lock, release it.
        if (enteredUpgLock)
        {
            _readerWriterLock.ExitUpgradeableReadLock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would work, except I do not know if a particular thread wants to write until it reads the values from the list (there are different "write" conditions for each thread)